# Struggling with displaying checkbox data in DetailView page

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a form that when i submit it need to show the details I submitted in the form.
I am really struggling to understand how to get it to display checkbox data.

I went thropugh the django documentation on DetailForms but this didnt really help me with how to display ManyToManyFields.

My template is as follows:

```
<li>{{theBurger.burger}}</li>
<li>{{theBurger.bun}}</li>
{% for toppings in theBurger.toppings.all %}
<li>{{toppings}}</li>
{% empty %}
<p>No toppings!</p>
{% endfor %}
<li>{{theBurger.sauces}}</li>
{% for extras in theBurger.extras.all %}
<li>{{theBurger.extras}}</li>
{% empty%}
<p>No extras!</p>
{% endfor %}
```

My view is as followes:

```
class OrderDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'theBurger'
    slug_field = 'id'
    model = models.Burger

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OrderDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        return context
```

I can get the page to display all the other information except information that has been submitted via checkboxes. the response that is being sent is:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 
['l6Qq7tg89cueHV2Fl6Qq7tg89cueHV2F2WrzrbJ'], 
'burger': ["Aurion's Famous Beef Burger"], 'bun': ['White Bread'], 
'toppings': ['15', '1
6'], 'sauces': ['Our Zesty Barbaque Sauce'], 'Submit': ['Git my food!']}>
```

Lastly here is the form:

```
class BurgerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BurgerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['toppings'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        for field_name in self.fields:
            field = self.fields.get(field_name)
            if field and isinstance(field , forms.TypedChoiceField):
                field.choices = field.choices[1:]
        self.fields['extras'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()

    class Meta:
        model = Burger
        fields = ['burger', 'bun', 'toppings', 'sauces', 'extras']
```

Can someone point out what ive done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Darn after ploughing though a gazillion google linked I came across this:

http://www.joshuakehn.com/2013/6/23/django-m2m-modelform.html

I tried to remove the:

```
Commit=False
```

from:

```
post = form.save()
```

in the forms.py file and it works now.  I wasted a lot of time on this so I hope it helps someone else.